how to create pdf by dompdf with background image?
i use simply following to print some data in pdf by dompdf in my codeigniter 3 project. here is my controller method:
public function index() {
    // Load Dompdf library
    $dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();

    // HTML content with background image inline
    $html = '
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        body {
            background-image: base_url('uploads/background_images/CoverImage1.jpg');
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h2>Background Image</h2>

        <p style="color:red">By default, the background image will repeat itself if it is smaller than the element where it is specified, in this case the body element.</p>

        </body>
        </html>
    ';

    // Load HTML to Dompdf
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

    // Set base path for resolving relative URLs
    $dompdf->setBasePath(realpath(FCPATH . 'uploads/background_images/'));

    // Render PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // Output PDF to browser
    $dompdf->stream("hello_world.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
}

the pdf created but background image missed.
how should i define background images for dompdf 3.0.0.
can any one help to resolve?
thanks in advance.

You almost have it
Try:
body { 
    background-image: url(base_url('uploads/background_images/CoverImage1.jpg'));
}

Instead of:
body {
    background-image: base_url('uploads/background_images/CoverImage1.jpg');
}

Good luck
